# I need a solution to show pdf

Tags: javascript, html

When I link to a pdf file in a web form the acrobat reader handles loading it. but I need an activex object or client script to show the pdf file not the acrobat reader software. I couldn't find anything(I need it completely free not trial).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a 3rt party API like Google Books or Google Docs.

[Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/) also provides an API.

Comment: This application is used in an internal network(LAN) Not WWW.

Answer (score 1):

to add pdf rendering to firefox they put together, `pdf.js` ([about](http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/), [source](https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js/)), a pure javascript pdf renderer.

it might be a possible option.

Comment: This looks like a really nice project. Unfortunately it would not be suitable for production - tried viewing the demo document in Chrome and there were rendering issues in diagrams. Certainly one to keep an eye on.

Comment: @user1170892 i've personally tested it in Chrome 12.0.742.30 (Official Build 84361) dev, so it isn't just for firefox although that might be its main target. but i do admit that its not finished.

Answer (score 1):

id have done this google doc viewer

```
$(function(){
    var links = $("a.pdf,a.doc,a.xls");
    var docs = links.attr("href");
    var gog = "&embedded=true";
    var polurl = window.location.hostname;
    var baseurl  = "http://docs.google.com/gview?url="+polurl+'/';

    $(links).click(function(e){

    var conents = $('<iframe id="helpmeplease" src="'+baseurl+encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('href'))+gog+'" style="width:900px; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>')
    $('#helpmeplease').attr('src',baseurl+encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('href'))+gog)
    $.fancybox({
        'content'           :conents,
        'width'             : 1000,
        'height'            : 800,
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    })
    e.preventDefault()
});
});
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/download.htm). Which has a commercial and a free GPL version with branding logo visible. I personally don't find the logo that annoying but leave that up to you.

Comment: FlexPaper needs to convert pdf to swf. I dont want to do that.

Any other idea?